# With Azure Data Factory how can I unfold Objects of objects?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have this data

[image]

The RuleManifestsProperty contains objects "1", "Latitude" and "pumpe". I need a way unpivot these objects so each objectClassId gets every single object.

It is very important that the objects names are applied dynamically. It differs what kind of objects that I am handling.

I have tried with Unpivot but with no luck.

This is the object structure of the objects. They share the same object structure.

(propertyAlias as boolean, propertyModelDtid as boolean, propertyModelLegacy as boolean, propertyType as string, regexExtension as string)

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: Is it possible to unpivot objects from RuleManifestsProperty object?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unpivot? Provide sample source data and expected output so the issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot transformation does not support columns with complex data type. In order to achieve the requirement, you can use the flatten transformation followed by parse transformation. Below is the detailed approach.

**Sample Input data:**

```json
[
    {
    "ObjectClassId":"aaaa",
    "RuleManifestsProperty":{
    "1":{
        "propertyAlias":1,
        "propertyModelDtid":1,
        "propertyModelLegacy":0,
        "propertyType":"type1",
        "regexExtension":"re1"
        },
    "Latitude":null,
    "pumpe":null    
    }
    },
    {
        "ObjectClassId":"bbbb",
        "RuleManifestsProperty":{
        "1":null,   
        "Latitude":{
        "propertyAlias":0,
        "propertyModelDtid":1,
        "propertyModelLegacy":0,
        "propertyType":"type2",
        "regexExtension":"re2"
        },
        "pumpe":null
        }
    },
    {
        "ObjectClassId":"cccc",
        "RuleManifestsProperty":{
        "1":null,
        "Latitude":null,
        "pumpe":{
        "propertyAlias":0,
        "propertyModelDtid":0,
        "propertyModelLegacy":0,
        "propertyType":"type3",
        "regexExtension":"re3"
        }
        }
    }
]
```

- Source transformation is taken with the sample Json dataset.
- Derived column transformation (derivedColumn1) is taken to convert the complex datatype of `RuleManifestsProperty` field to string.
  **Expression:**`toString(RuleManifestsProperty)`

[image]

- Then derived column transformation (derivedColumn2) is taken again to convert the string data (which was originally Json of Json object type) to array of Json.

**Expression**:`split(replace(replace(replace(RuleManifestsProperty,'}}','}'),'{"1','"1'),'},','}},'),'},')`

This expression will remove the characters `{` and `}` which are in the beginning and end of each row. Then It will replace  `},`  with `}},`. This is done to split the string data into array basis the characters `},`.

[image]

- Then flatten transformation is taken and Flatten settings is given as

```
Unroll by: RuleManifestsProperty []
Unroll root: RuleManifestsProperty []
```

[image]

- Derived column transformation (derivedColumn3) is taken to split the "1","latitude","pumpe" in one column and their value in another column.

**Expression:**

```
RuleManifestsProperty =  split(replace(RuleManifestsProperty,':{',':{{'),':{')[1]

Value =  split(replace(RuleManifestsProperty,':{',':{{'),':{')[2]
```

[image]

- Then Parse transformation is taken and settings is given as,

```
format:JSON
Document form: Single document
Columns:
Column:Value
Expression:Value
Output column type: (propertyAlias as boolean, propertyModelDtid as boolean,
propertyModelLegacy as boolean,
propertyType as string,
regexExtension as string)
```

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

| ObjectClassId | RuleManifestsProperty | propertyAlias | propertyModelDtid | propertyModelLegacy | propertyType | regexExtension |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | type1 | re1 |
| aaaa | Latitude | null | null | null | null | null |
| aaaa | pumpe | null | null | null | null | null |
| bbbb | 1 | null | null | null | null | null |
| bbbb | Latitude | 0 | 1 | 0 | type2 | re2 |
| bbbb | pumpe | null | null | null | null | null |
| cccc | 1 | null | null | null | null | null |
| cccc | Latitude | null | null | null | null | null |
| cccc | pumpe | 0 | 0 | 0 | type3 | re3 |